# Get Checkmark rows in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I have checked some rows programatically at cellForRowAtIndexPath, and it is showing and working fine. But now I need to fetch the check marked rows. I use the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

    if([motorwayTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:index].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        NSLog(@"Selected Rows: %d",i);
    }
}
```

And here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arefin %d",[indexPath row]];

if(indexPath.row == 8 || indexPath.row == 7 || indexPath.row == 9)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.selected = YES;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

return cell;
```

}

But the problem is I am getting only visible check marked rows, not getting that are not visible yet. How I can get check marked rows that are not visible yet in UITableView but checked programatically in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're only getting the visible rows is because cells are released when you scroll them offscreen. Instead of your current solution, I'd recommend overriding the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. In this method, test whether the cell at the index path passed into the method has a checkmark, and if so, store the index path in an `NSMutableSet` accordingly.

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
            [_selectedCellIndexes addObject:indexPath];
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 And I would recommend to use a `NSMutableSet`. It's the right choice for this task. You don't need order, and want to save each indexPath exactly one time. So you can benefit from the performance gain that comes by using NS*Sets

Comment: @The Kraken, I am not getting check marked rows. Please be informed that I am checked the rows in cellForRowAtIndexPath with cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.selected = YES; based on some condition. And now I need to get those check marked rows without manually selecting a row. So, what is your suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you manually check the rows, then you should already have their index paths...?